# How to get an image to display in Picturbox from a Listbox selected item

Tags: c#

Everything works fine until I actually call the SetPicture() Method. Any ideas as to why the image will not display when the selected item is changed. Right now i only have one image preset until i figure out my problem. Thanks for any help

```
namespace CelestialWindowsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List CelestialLibrary = new List(); private static CelestialBody celestialBody; private static string name; private static string description; private static string image; public static CelestialBody NewPlanet { get { return celestialBody; } set { celestialBody = value; } }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateLibrary();
        }

        public void PopulateLibrary()//Runs when the Form 1 is loaded. Adds preset item into the ListNox.
        {
            CelestialLibrary = new List<CelestialBody>();
            CelestialBody cb1 = new CelestialBody("Earth", "Our Home", @"C:\Users\Cassidy\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CelestialWindowsApp\CelestialWindowsApp\ImageResources\earthimage.jpg");
            CelestialBody cb2 = new CelestialBody("Mars", "4th planet from the sun.");
            CelestialBody cb3 = new CelestialBody("Venus", "2nd planet from the son");

            CelestialLibrary.Add(cb1);
            CelestialLibrary.Add(cb3);
            lbLibrary.DataSource = CelestialLibrary;
            foreach (var p in CelestialLibrary)
            {
                lbLibrary.DisplayMember = "ShowBodies";
            }
        }

        public void AddItem() // Adds the new Item to my library and then adds to and updates the ListBox;
        {
            CelestialBody cb;
            name = txtboxName.Text;
            description = txtboxDescription.Text;
            image = txtboxImagePath.Text;
            cb = new CelestialBody(name, description, image);
            CelestialLibrary.Add(cb);
            MessageBox.Show(name + " has been added to the Library.");
            txtboxName.Text = null;
            txtboxDescription.Text = null;
            lbLibrary.DataSource = null;
            lbLibrary.DataSource = CelestialLibrary;
            lbLibrary.DisplayMember = "ShowBodies";
        }
        public void DisplayItemInfo()//Displays the current selected item information.
        {
            List<CelestialBody> bodyList = (List<CelestialBody>)lbLibrary.DataSource;
            CelestialBody currentItem = bodyList[lbLibrary.SelectedIndex];
            foreach (CelestialBody cb in bodyList)
            {
                if (currentItem.MyId == cb.MyId)
                    celestialBody = new CelestialBody(cb.Name, cb.Description, cb.ImagePath);
                {
                    txtboxItemInfo.Text = celestialBody.Description;
                    SetPicture(celestialBody.ImagePath);
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetPicture(string image)
        {
            if (picboxBodyImage.Image != null)
            {
                picboxBodyImage.Image.Dispose();
            }
            picboxBodyImage.ImageLocation = image;
        }

        private void btnAddNewBody_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddItem();
        }

        private void lbLibrary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayItemInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the value of the `image` argument and determine if it is valid?

Comment: Everytime it runs the image value always shows null and I cannot figure out why. All other info is displayed properly except the image.The images are stored in a solution folder.

Comment: Im only about a week into learning c# sorry if code is a mess.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is with the `ImagePath` property of `CelestialBody`, not anything to do with a `PictureBox`.

Comment: That sounds like it could be it. I am off to work and will check it out when I get home. Thankyou all for the help so far. I will let you know if I get it running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the path in variable `image`. Assuming path is correct, Try below

```
picboxBodyImage.Image = Image.FromFile(image);
```

Comment: My ImagePath variable was set to private in CelestialBody. Thankyou everyone! Everything works great now.